# Adding a button to a custom InfoWindowAdapter view that can register clicks

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm adding an InfoWindowAdapter with a custom layout to the Android Google Maps API v2 based map fragment. I've put a button in the view I return from getInfoWindow() and while it shows up perfectly fine, when I click on said button the window itself registers a click (blinking with a yellowish tint as usual) while the button does not.

How can I make a button in the info window "clickable"? And, by extension, any view inside an info window?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-android-api-v2-interactive-infowindow-like-in-original-android-go

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead, listen for marker click events with OnMarkerClickListener and display your own complete view directly. It may be a bit more work to anchor it to the location of the marker, however. Try [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) with showAtLocation(View parent, int gravity, int x, int y)

Answer (score 10):

While you can set an info window to be an arbitrary view using [`GoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setInfoWindowAdapter%28com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter%29), the info window that is rendered on the map is not a live view.  Instead, it is a snapshot of the view at the time the view was returned by the adapter (see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#info_windows)).  So, unfortunately it doesn't behave like a standard view once it is placed on the map.

Comment: Hi Anthony, Where did you find documentation stating that it is a snapshot?  I've only come across answers by you stating this - but nothing in the Google docs (as limited as those tend to be).

Comment: There's a note in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows#custom_info_windows) that has this information.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can set a customize AlartDialog in InfoWindowClickListener to switch something event

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {          
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            String[] items={"onefunction","twofunction"};
            AlertDialog.Builder itemDilog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            itemDilog.setTitle("");
            itemDilog.setCancelable(false);
            itemDilog.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch(which){
                    case 0:{
                            onefunction();
                            }break;
                    case 1:{
                            twofunction();
                            }break; 
                    }

                }
            });
            itemDilog.show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: No, that's not what he/she is asking for.

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-android-api-v2-interactive-infowindow-like-in-original-android-go

Answer (score 0):

CustomInfoWindowAdapter set tag:

```
mWindow.findViewById(R.id.chat).setTag("chatTag"); // button
```

and:

```
  @Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {


   if(customInfoWindowAdapter.getInfoContents(marker).findViewById(R.id.chat).getTag().equals("chatTag")) {
      // any code here
   }
}
```