# How can I add a button to a marker's info window?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I would like to implement this in my app, but I have no idea of how to make the marker have a button, or how to have the OnMarkerClickListener tell me what part it clicked on.

As an example, here is the official Maps app, where the directions icon is a separate part/button and the right side shows reviews.

[image: Example]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a button to a custom InfoWindowAdapter view that can register clicks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706925/adding-a-button-to-a-custom-infowindowadapter-view-that-can-register-clicks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are using the new version of the [Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)

While you can set an info window to be an arbitrary view using [`GoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setInfoWindowAdapter%28com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter%29), the info window that is rendered on the map is not a live view.  Instead, it is a snapshot of the view at the time the view was returned by the adapter.  So, unfortunately there is currently no way to distinguish between click events on the info window.

Answer (score 3):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13714352/1664556) moments ago:
nstead, listen for marker click events with OnMarkerClickListener and display your own complete view directly. It may be a bit more work to anchor it to the location of the marker, however. Try PopupWindow with showAtLocation(View parent, int gravity, int x, int y)

Answer (score 1):

You can basically push the desired html code into the InfoWindow 's content property.

as reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows

Comment: Any idea on how to do it with the android v2 api?

Comment: sorry, I afterwards realized it was about the android version of the API

For Android version seems to be a bit different: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#info_windows

Comment: Yep, this question is for Android, not the Javascript API.

Answer (score 0):

The "bubble" is just another view that is placed on top of the map.  So your `OnMarkerClickedListener` will tell you which pin was clicked.  From there you can get the actual position of the pin on the screen and use that to position the bubble view which will just contain normal Android widgets.

Comment: have any link to do that