# Android Google Maps v2 add new building labels with markers

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am currently writing an android application and I would like to add some new labels to the buildings. I have successfully add text on top of the buildings by using marks with custom icon/bitmap detailed in here:

[android Maps API v2 with custom markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763545/android-maps-api-v2-with-custom-markers)

However, is there a way to make the text looks as similar as the ones google has? (i.e. white trim with grey color)
I am able to set the color gray with `setColor(Color.GRAY)` but am unable to replicate the white trim around the words.

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using a version of `setColor()` that takes in RGB parameters?

Comment: The `setColor()` I use contains RGB as well as aplha. But if you use Google maps on an android phone, you'll notice there is a white trim around the gray words. There's where I am stuck at.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do, the Maps API doesn't really let you do custom drawing