# how to put set of latitude longitude into Google map

Tags: android, web-services, google-maps

I have to create a project where a list of latitude and longitude will be shown on Google maps. Those locations will come from web service. I have implemented GPS for current location, Google map. But how to put all these locations on Google map with a marker. I am little confuse on that. Code as well as ideas are welcome.

Comment: there are lots of example what you have tried till now?

Comment: try the following thing 

[for markers on map][1]

[for path between two points][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763545/android-maps-api-v2-with-custom-markers
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702621/answer-draw-path-between-two-points-using-google-maps-android-api-v2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go this [Reference Link](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-multiple-marker-locations-in-google-maps-android-api-v2-and-save-it-in-shared-preferences/) . In this site you will answer of your question.

Answer (score 9):

You can use this:

**Layout XML:**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp" >

            <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/YOURMAPID"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
            </com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>
        </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

**Initialize the map:**

```
private GoogleMap googleMap = ((MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.YOURMAPID)).getMap();
```

**Set the marker:**

```
 googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng( YOUR LATITUDE, -YOUR LOINGITUDE)).title("Marker"));
```

Comment: Please, remember to add compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2' to the app's build.gradle to have it work.