# How to specify the size of the icon on the Marker in Google Maps V2 Android

Tags: android, google-maps, size, marker

In may app i use Map from Google Maps V2 and in this map i am trying to add markers each Marker with an icon, but the marker is taking the size of the icon which is making the icon looks flue.
How can i specify the size of the marker in **dp** so that i can control how it looks like on the map

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Currently it's not possible to specify a marker size using [`MarkerOptions`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions), so your only option is to rescale your `Bitmap` before setting it as your marker icon.

Creating the scaled Bitmap:

```
int height = 100;
int width = 100;
BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.marker);
Bitmap b = bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
```

Using `smallMarker` as the marker icon:

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(POSITION)
        .title("Your title")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker))
);
```

Answer (score 29):

The accepted answer is outdated (`Resources::getDrawable` has been deprecated since API level 22). Here's an updated version:

```
int height = 100;
int width = 100;
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable. marker);
Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
BitmapDescriptor smallMarkerIcon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker);
```

and then apply it in MarkerOption

```
.icon(smallMarkerIcon)
```

Answer (score 9):

**Kotlin version** 
I used 0- 9 answer and used it with kotlin

```
fun generateHomeMarker(context: Context): MarkerOptions {
    return MarkerOptions()
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(generateSmallIcon(context)))
}

fun generateSmallIcon(context: Context): Bitmap {
    val height = 100
    val width = 100
    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.logo)
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can look for an answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763545/android-maps-api-v2-with-custom-markers), where it already explained how to create a custom marker, with a given width and height by creating a dynamic **bitmap**.

Answer (score 0):

```
Drawable circleDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.primarysplitter);
bitmapDescriptor = getMarkerIconFromDrawable(circleDrawable);

private BitmapDescriptor getMarkerIconFromDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._30sdp), (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._30sdp));
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
}
```